# Running RMarkdown report with Distill - Pandoc Failing with Error 127

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Seems like a perennial question, but one without an answer.

### Set Up

I am running up R inside a Docker container, inside a lambda function. Current memory limit of Lambda is 10GB plus 10GB ephemeral memory.

In my docker, I choose my packages etc:

```
ENV R_VERSION=4.0.3
RUN tar xvzf pandoc-2.17.1.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

And then after a bit more messing about, I eventually run:

```
rmarkdown::render(
  input  = report_rmd,
  params = param_list,
  output_file = output_file,
  output_dir  = output_dir,
  rmd_file    = "home.rmd"
  intermediates_dir = temporary_directory,
  envir = new.env()
)
```

### Error

The rmarkdown completes but when I supply large enough datasets to the report, it will fail with this error:

```
pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
Duration: 71455 ms Memory Size: 10240 MB Max Memory Used: 6592 MB
```

The duration & memory are reported by my Lambda instance. It appears that I have heaps more memory to work with but some research into this error suggests that it's a memory problem.

### Pandoc Arg +RTS -K1m -RTS

I've seen a suggestion to change the pandoc stack size in the rmarkdown YAML header, but I can't get make sense of this. On my local machine, I can experiment quickly so I've made this change - expecting this to fail:

```
output: 
  distill::distill_article:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    theme: theme.css
    pandoc_args: [
      "+RTS", "-K1m",
      "-RTS"
    ]
```

I've reduced it to 1m for a reasonably large run and it seems to work fine. And I **can** see the change reflected in the command that is executed.

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS full.knit.md --to html5 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output full.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\thebi\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\thebi\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained +RTS -K1m -RTS --standalone --table-of-contents
```

You need to scroll over quite far but it's there! `+RTS -K1m -RTS`. Oddly the default value is still included first.

So I then reduce it to 128k, and hey presto, we have a useful (if irrelevant) error message:

```
pandoc.exe: Stack space overflow: current size 33624 bytes.
pandoc.exe: Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
```

Questions:

1. Looks like my problem is *not* related to the +RTS memory issue. As it happens, I could probably claw back 500MB of memory. So any ideas what error 127 does mean?  It takes nearly a day to rebuild my docker so I'd like to have some confidence in what my plan is...
2. Are my versions of R and pandoc likely to be OK? Is this a problem that has been successfully solved elsewhere - if so how can I use this to solve it here?